# What does "death" intuitively mean in the paper "Death and Suicide in Universal Artificial Intelligence"?

Tags: research, definitions, agi, death, aixi

In the paper [Death and Suicide in Universal Artificial Intelligence](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.00652.pdf), a proposal is given for what death could mean for Artificial Intelligence.

What does this mean using English only? I understand that mathematical notation is useful for giving a precise definition, but I'd like to understand what the definition really means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The authors do actually give an English definition in terms of the well-known agent formulation of AI:

> We intend this usage to be intuitive: death means that one sees
>   no more percepts, and takes no more actions.

It would seem that this becomes possible for a reinforcement learning agent such as AIXI in a formulation that uses *semi-measures* of probability (which need not sum up to 1), rather than the more traditional notion.